# How to apply timeout on method in Erlang?

Tags: concurrency, erlang, timeout

Is there a way to apply timeout on simple module method call,
As example,

```
my_method(Name)->
  timer:sleep(2000),
  io:format("hello world ~p!~n",[Name]).
```

I want to add timeout option to above method, is there a way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply/add timeout"?  Like call a function and wait for a reply for a fixed duration and return an error if it doesn't respond within that duration?

Comment: @Dogbert, yes exactly..

Comment: Regardless of whether you use a gen_server or just spawn a simple process to do the work, you need to have two processes: one executing the call, and the other waiting for a result or a timeout. And there are some things to think about. In case of a timeout, you need to decide what to do about the unfinished call: should you kill it, or just let it run to completion but drop the final return value? And if you kill it, could that leave an inconsistent state in case the call has side effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could spawn your function and wait for a a message back. You can set a timeout while you wait on the receive.

```
 my_method(Name)->
  YourTimeOut = 10,
  Self = self(),
  _Pid = spawn(fun()-> 
                  timer:sleep(2000),
                  io:format("hello world ~p!~n",[Name]),
                  Self ! {self(), ok} end),
  receive
    {_PidSpawned, ok} -> ok
  after
     YourTimeOut -> timout
  end.
```

Answer (score 1):

See `gen:call/3,4` implementation. It is done by

```
do_call(Process, Label, Request, Timeout) ->
    try erlang:monitor(process, Process) of
    Mref ->
        %% If the monitor/2 call failed to set up a connection to a
        %% remote node, we don't want the '!' operator to attempt
        %% to set up the connection again. (If the monitor/2 call
        %% failed due to an expired timeout, '!' too would probably
        %% have to wait for the timeout to expire.) Therefore,
        %% use erlang:send/3 with the 'noconnect' option so that it
        %% will fail immediately if there is no connection to the
        %% remote node.

        catch erlang:send(Process, {Label, {self(), Mref}, Request},
          [noconnect]),
        receive
        {Mref, Reply} ->
            erlang:demonitor(Mref, [flush]),
            {ok, Reply};
        {'DOWN', Mref, _, _, noconnection} ->
            Node = get_node(Process),
            exit({nodedown, Node});
        {'DOWN', Mref, _, _, Reason} ->
            exit(Reason)
        after Timeout -> %% <-- HERE
            erlang:demonitor(Mref, [flush]),
            exit(timeout)
        end
    catch
    error:_ ->
        %% Node (C/Java?) is not supporting the monitor.
        %% The other possible case -- this node is not distributed
        %% -- should have been handled earlier.
        %% Do the best possible with monitor_node/2.
        %% This code may hang indefinitely if the Process 
        %% does not exist. It is only used for featureweak remote nodes.
        Node = get_node(Process),
        monitor_node(Node, true),
        receive
        {nodedown, Node} -> 
            monitor_node(Node, false),
            exit({nodedown, Node})
        after 0 -> 
            Tag = make_ref(),
            Process ! {Label, {self(), Tag}, Request},
            wait_resp(Node, Tag, Timeout) %% <-- HERE for C/Java nodes
        end
    end.
```